# Как получить бит-маску аналогично функции BIN_TO_NUM без запроса?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Есть функция [BIN_TO_NUM](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/BIN_TO_NUM.html#GUID-BF061402-D7F0-4557-B7D4-1CEE6E80F3B2). В докумнетации есть даже пример того, что хотелось бы:

```
DECLARE
  warehouse NUMBER := 1;
  ground    NUMBER := 1;
  insured   NUMBER := 1;
  result    NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT BIN_TO_NUM(warehouse, ground, insured) INTO result FROM DUAL;
END;
```

То есть, получить бит-маску. Но хотелось бы иметь эту функцию в PL/SQL, в котором она недоступна:

```
declare n number; begin n := bin_to_num (1,0,1,1); end;
/
PLS-00201: identifier 'BIN_TO_NUM' must be declared
```

Можно ли получить этот же результат без статического SQL запроса?

Answer (score 2):

Написать свой аналог функции:

```
var mask number
declare
    subtype bit is binary_integer range 0..1 not null;
    type bits is table of bit;
    function bin2num (flags bits) return number is
        ret number := 0;
    begin
        for f in 1..flags.count loop 
            ret := ret*2 + flags(f); end loop;
        return ret;
    end; 
begin 
    declare
        warehouse constant bit := 1;
        ground    constant bit := 1;
        insured   constant bit := 1;
    begin
        :mask  := bin2num (bits (warehouse, ground, insured));
    end;    
end; 
/
```

Результат:

```
print mask 

      MASK
----------
         7
```